# Lua tem variáveis estáticas e dinâmicas no heap?

Tags: variáveis, lua, gerenciamento-de-memória, tempo-de-vida

A vinculação de armazenamento (relacionada ao tempo de vida da variável) permite variáveis estáticas? Permite variáveis dinâmicas de *heap*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem algumas definições do que seria variável estática. Lua não tem mecanismo de variável estática, mas é poderosa e flexível para obter o mesmo resultado, através de outros mecanismos.

Por padrão valores são colocados no *heap* através de alocação dinâmica e variáveis podem apontar para esses valores. Você usa `local` para mudar para alocação automática na *stack*.

Comment: Agradeço pela ajuda!